# Retrieve Outlook info account from multi profile

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am working on an Outlook inventory powershel script (see also [powershell calculated properties for multiple values](https://serverfault.com/questions/890559/powershell-calculated-properties-for-multiple-values))

This code work great, but only with the default Outlook profile. I need retrieve data from all Outlook profiles

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$namespace.Accounts | Select-Object DisplayName, SmtpAddress, UserName, AccountType, ExchangeConnectionMode | Sort-Object  -Property SmtpAddress | Format-Table
```

Part of solution is get Outlook profile list:

```
 Get-childItem -Path "HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles"
```

And run previous code against each profile obtained. Here is where my cry for help shows up :) 
How could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) to retrieve the [IProfAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/iprofadminiunknown) interface, loop through all profiles, and list all services.

If Extended MAPI is not an option, you can use the [ProfMan](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman.htm) library (I am its author, it comes with the distributable version of [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption)):

http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#example1 :

```
'Enumerate and print the names of all services in all profiles
set Profiles=CreateObject("ProfMan.Profile")
for i = 1 to Profiles.Count
  set Profile = Profiles.Item(i)
  set Services = Profile.Services
  Debug.Print "------ " & Profile.Name & " ------"
  for j = 1 to Services.Count
    Debug.Print Services.Item(j).ServiceName
  next
next
```