# Powershell - Trying to remove PSTs from all mail profiles

Tags: powershell, outlook, office-automation

I am using the below script to remove all PSTs from an Outlook profile, then delete the PST files. However, it seems that this can only grab the default mail profile.

```
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Namespace = $Outlook.getNamespace("MAPI")
    $folderCheckVAR = Get-Item -Path "C:\temp" -ea Ignore
    if ($folderCheckVAR.Exists)
    {
        Remove-Item "C:\temp\PST_Paths.csv" -ea Ignore
    }
    else
    {
        New-Item -Path "C:\" -Name "temp" -ItemType "directory" -ea Ignore
    }

    $all_psts = $Namespace.Stores | Where-Object {($_.ExchangeStoreType -eq '3') -and                                                 
    ($_.FilePath -like '*.pst') -and ($_.IsDataFileStore -eq $true)}

    ForEach ($pst in $all_psts){
        $outputVAR = [pscustomobject]@{
                       "FilePath" = $pst.FilePath
                       }
        $outputVAR | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Path "c:\temp\Pst_Paths.csv"
        $Outlook.Session.RemoveStore($pst.GetRootFolder())
    }

    if (Get-Process Outlook -ea SilentlyContinue) {
        Get-Process Outlook | Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null } | Stop- 
   Process -Force
    }

    #Delay between Outlook close and file deletion to ensure Outlook closed completely
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    $csv = "C:\temp\PST_Paths.csv"
    $pstPaths = Import-CSV $csv
    foreach ($path in $pstPaths) {
        Remove-Item $path.FilePath
    }
```

These three lines are what grab the mail profile and grab the PSTs:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Namespace = $Outlook.getNamespace("MAPI")
$all_psts = $Namespace.Stores | Where-Object {($_.ExchangeStoreType -eq '3') -and                                                 
($_.FilePath -like '*.pst') -and ($_.IsDataFileStore -eq $true)}
```

Is there a way that I can adjust this be able to get all mail profiles on the user account, not just the default?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Outlook is a singleton - only one instance of outlook.exe can run at any given time. You can loop through all profiles, start Outlook (by creating an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object), log to the given profile by calling `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")` / `Namespace.Logon("ProfileName")`, run your code, then close Outlook by calling `Application.Quit`, then repeat the loop for the next profile. Hardly efficient, as each profile might require the user to log in.
If Outlook is already running, calling `Namespace.Logon` will do nothing - you would need to close it first before starting in a different profile.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi only), you can do that without starting Outlook or initializing a MAPI session using the [IProfAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/iprofadminiunknown) interface. You can get a list of profiles using `IProfAdmin::GetProfileTable`, open each profile by calling `IProfAdmin::AdminServices`, find all `MSPST` or `MSUPST` services and delete them using `IMsgServiceAdmin::DeleteMsgService`. You can play with these interfaces in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IProfAdmin button).

If Extended MAPI in C++ or Delphi are not an option, you can use the [ProfMan](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman.htm) library (I am also its author) - it wraps the profile management interfaces and can be used from any language, including PS. You can modify the [example](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#example2) at the ProfMan site to delete the PST services.

Comment: That's awesome, definitely puts me in the right direction. I have another question though. I can't seem to find a way to get a list of each of the mail profiles. I am trying to automate this for multiple users, so I won't be able to explicitly state each profile. Do you know if there's a way to get a list of the profiles, put them into an array?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986760/where-does-microsoft-outlook-for-office-365-save-profiles-info

Comment: As well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497127/retrieve-outlook-info-account-from-multi-profile